# Can't set the priority of a service

Tags: service, windows-10

I noticed that my fan goes up a lot on occasion for no apparent reason. Investigation shows that it's the process *Antimalware Service Executable*, the service *Windows Defender Antivirus Service* and the file executed is *MsMpEng.exe*.

I want it to be able to run still but not go bananas, so I tried to set its priority to low. However, Windows barked at me that the operation could not be completed and that access was denied.

How can I force the service to run at a limited performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, by design. That "by design" means that if you find a hack, a future security update of Windows will likely render your hack inoperable.

The key word here is "security". The whole point of anti-malware is that detects malware even when the malware tries to avoid detection. To make that work, Windows treats anti-malware software as a special case, and offers it additional protection. If there was an answer to your question, it would be treated by Microsoft as a bug.

Comment: Well, duck... I see your point there. What if I'm not against the service running but wish to let it go on partial speed? Security issue is important but it's not being voided just because my fan will go down from this crazy-donkey-speed. Or are you saying that's simply no go and whatever I do, the fan will go bananas like that?

Comment: @KonradViltersten: That doesn't work either. This is an on-access file scanner. It scans for malware when any program opens files. Slowing it down slows down every program that's waiting for the file to be OK'ed.

Comment: Well, double duck, then... I like the idea of being secure. I dislike the idea that it's being pushed down my throat not giving me the option to duck up things, should I chose to do be stupid.